# Regular CPU spikes ever 5 seconds. Clean install SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, agent

I have a fresh box (Server 2012 R2, 16GB RAM, 2.6GHz), fresh install on SQL 2014. Set up replication to another box, same spec (fresh installs.)

There is nothing happening on the box, no connections open. Only replication is running. I'm seeing very regular CPU spikes ever 5 seconds or so. I have to put this down to replciation as when i stop the SQL Agent service the spikes drop off. I have exactly the same setup running in production on SQL Server 2008 R2 with no issues.

Anyone got an idea what could be causing this?

The image below shows the spikes. the are no changes happening to the data, so the box should be twiddling its thumbs...

Comment: sorry, couldn't add the image. the spike go up to about 50% every 5 secs.

Comment: More info, the distribution agent jobs are causing this...but why?

Comment: What happens if you put a tracer in the replication connection?

Comment: Distrib to Subscriber 4s, Total 8s

Comment: When you say "same setup running in production", that implies that this is not production. I would guess that you have fewer resources in non-prod as you do in prod. So you may be consuming the same amount in absolute resources but it shows up as a bigger spike because it's larger by way of percentage.

Comment: Turns out the answer was to turn off immediate_sync on the publications. This blog did the job. http://jasonbrimhall.info/2014/01/05/day-12-high-cpu-and-bloat-in-distribution/